# Sine and Cosine - Complex integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to show that for all $w \in \mathbb{C}$ we have
$$
\int_{\gamma_w} \sin (z) d z=0, \quad \int_{\gamma_w} \cos (z) d z=0,
$$
where the curve $\gamma_w:[0,2 \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is given by
$$
\gamma_w(t)=t+w .
$$

---

Can I just say
$$
  \int_{\gamma_w} \sin (z)  d z =\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin(t+w) d t=[-\cos(t+w)]=0. 
  $$
and for $\cos(z)$ likewise?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, given this parametrisation one finds that $d \gamma_{w} (t) = dt$ which gives that the integral is equal to $-cos(t+w)|_{0}^{2 \pi} = 0$.